# Android Studios Splash Screen stops

Tags: android-studio, splash-screen

I am having this problem with android studios splash screen every time I run the emulator and run the app it stops after the splash screen. my SplashScreen.java code looks good from what I had seen from others. I believe the problem is in the manifest, but can not seem to figure it out. The logcat doesn't to show any problem. I'm just stuck, so any help would be appreciated.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mook.bodyshop">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Don's Body Shop"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.mook.bodyshop.MainActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

that is the manifest. Here is the SplashScreen.java

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
/*Thread myThread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(1000);
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

};
    myThread.start();*/
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    };
    Timer opening = new Timer();
    opening.schedule(task, 5000);
}
}
```

Then here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mook.bodyshop;

import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And lastly the logcat.

```
05-20 20:55:56.809 2826-2826/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-20 20:55:56.811 2826-2826/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-20 20:55:56.912 2826-2826/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.mook.bodyshop-1/lib/x86
05-20 20:55:56.918 2826-2826/com.example.mook.bodyshop I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for com.example.mook.bodyshop
05-20 20:56:00.049 2826-2826/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-20 20:56:00.706 2826-2900/com.example.mook.bodyshop I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-20 20:56:00.706 2826-2900/com.example.mook.bodyshop D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
05-20 20:56:00.789 2826-2900/com.example.mook.bodyshop E/EGL_emulation: tid 2900: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
05-20 20:56:00.789 2826-2900/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xafdf71e0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
05-20 20:56:01.107 2826-2826/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
05-20 20:57:24.514 2826-2900/com.example.mook.bodyshop E/EGL_emulation: tid 2900: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
05-20 20:57:24.514 2826-2900/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xafdf71c0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
05-20 20:57:32.689 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.473ms
05-20 20:58:13.809 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.264ms
05-20 21:02:05.962 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.112ms
05-20 21:02:14.501 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.953ms
05-20 21:02:33.544 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.971ms
05-20 21:09:03.525 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.841ms
05-20 21:09:14.570 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.387ms
05-20 21:09:25.601 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.057ms
05-20 21:10:55.477 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.419ms
05-20 21:11:00.001 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.669ms
 05-20 21:11:08.070 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.188ms
 05-20 21:13:12.125 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 23.024ms
 05-20 21:13:58.779 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.147ms
 05-20 21:14:12.845 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.171ms
 05-20 21:14:18.850 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.055ms
 05-20 21:15:02.487 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.034ms
 05-20 21:15:54.662 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.200ms
 05-20 21:16:02.691 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.037ms
 05-20 21:16:24.743 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.166ms
 05-20 21:18:55.781 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.182ms
 05-20 21:18:56.781 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.999ms
 05-20 21:19:55.990 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.446ms
 05-20 21:20:41.639 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.632ms
 05-20 21:21:59.857 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.553ms
 05-20 21:22:54.563 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.610ms
 05-20 21:22:57.065 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.631ms
 05-20 21:24:22.929 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 33.581ms
 05-20 21:24:47.231 2826-2833/com.example.mook.bodyshop W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.339ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I just answer my own question! The problem was that the SplashScreen was extending different than the MainActivity.

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

so I made them both extend `Activity`  because when I extended `AppCompatActivity` it would still stop after SplashScreen.